# How to update each column one at time for each row in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have 10 columns in my table and I want to update each column but one at a time for each row up to 10 rows.

if table is like

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

I want to update it like

```
x,2,3
4,y,6
7,8,z
```

Columns can be of any count so need dynamic approach. Also sometimes need to exclude some columns.

I tried to see if I can update row based on row id but there is no such option available as row id. I don't wanna change design of table to include a counter column.

Comment: What do you mean by "one at a time"? Should "X" in your example always be on the first row?

Comment: Like for first row, update first col. For second row update second col and so on

Comment: If you're not ordering the table by some key then the data in the first row can change every time - it's not deterministic. Is that okay?

Comment: Yeah its not an issue

Answer (score 0):

you can use window function to assign a a row id and based on that :

```
with cte as (
select * from ( 
   select * , row_number() over (order by id) rn
   from tablename
) t ) ;

update t 
set col1 = case when rn = 1 then <updatevalue> else col1 end
  , col2 = case when rn = 2 then <updatevalue> else col2 end
  , col3 = case when rn = 3 then <updatevalue> else col3 end
  , ...
from tablename t
join cte on cte.id = t.id
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong in syntax ? getting syntax issue in this

Comment: I don't think you can update CTE's like this in Snowflake

Comment: @EXODIA seems like snowflake doesn't support uneatable cte's , see if the updated answer works

Comment: What's that id col ? Original table has no such Id or primary key

Answer (score 0):

The requirement "Columns can be of any count so need dynamic approach" looks like as a try to implement matrix as a table.

Alternative approach could be usage of [ARRAY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_array.html) type and storing entire structure as single "cell" in the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t 
AS
SELECT ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(1,2,3),
                       ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(4,5,6),
                       ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(7,8,9)) c
UNION ALL
SELECT ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(10,20,30), 
                       ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(40,50,60), 
                       ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(70,80,90)) c;


SELECT *
FROM t;
/*
C
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]]
*/
```

Accessing elements:

```
SELECT c[0][0], c[0][1], c[0][2],
       c[1][0], c[1][1], c[1][2],
       c[2][0], c[2][1], c[2][2]
FROM t;
/*
C[0][0] C[0][1] C[0][2] C[1][0] C[1][1] C[1][2] C[2][0] C[2][1] C[2][2]
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90
*/
```

Update:

```
UPDATE t
SET c = ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('x'    , c[0][1], c[0][2])
                       ,ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(c[1][0], 'y'     ,c[1][2])
                       ,ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(c[2][0], c[2][1] , 'z'   )
                     );
                   
SELECT * FROM t;
/*
C
[["x",2,3],[4,"y",6],[7,8,"z"]]
[["x",20,30],[40,"y",60],[70,80,"z"]]
*/
```

More robust transformations could be performed via [user-defined functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/user-defined-functions.html).